# Function that returns a sub char string from given Indices

Tags: c++, substring, c-strings

Implement a function:

```
char* subCstring(char * inStr, int start_index, int end_index)
```

that takes as input an array of char which is a c-string and returns a c-string of the corresponding characters between start_index and end_index.

Comment: What does "between start_index and end_index" mean? Is it for example [start_index, end_index) or [start_index, end_index]?

Comment: It means the start_index means starting point in a c-string where we want to create a substring and end_string means upto that number we want to create the sub string

Comment: Are you allowed to destroy the input string?

Comment: Yes you can destroy input strings.

Comment: For example : if inStr ="ABCDEFG", start_index=1 and end_index=4, then returned c-string is "BCDE"

Comment: So"between" is inclusive?

Comment: Yeah "between " is inclusive

Comment: @Dante: This sounds like a homework assignment.  StackOverflow is not a homework service.  Please don't ask people to write your code for you, do your own homework.  If you are having troubles with something, post a [mcve] showing what you are actually doing.

Comment: @RemyLebeau This was actually question asked in my exam. This is not a homework assignment.

Comment: What is it with this C stuff?  I wish teachers would [stop teaching C when teaching C++](http://cppcast.com/2015/10/kate-gregory/)

Comment: @Dante -- The problem with this question is that you are given no guidelines on how you're supposed to  create this substring.  Is it a brand new allocated string?  Is it a "view" on the original string?  Is the original string modified?  Even a `C` programmer would have differing opinions on how a substring would be created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can cannibalize the input string, prematurely nulling it and returning a pointer further inside the string.

```
char* subCstring(char * inStr, int start_index, int end_index)
{
    inStr[end_index] = '\0'; // end_index + 1 if the end index is inclusive
    return &inStr[start_index];
}
```

Note this does no checking to ensure that start is less than end and both are within the bounds of the input string. You may need to add such checks.

Comment: It gives an error of memory access violation in either case. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Dante: That implies that you are accessing invalid memory, such as if `inStr` points to read-only memory, or your indexes are going out of bounds of the `inStr`.  Please provide a [mcve] showing what you are really doing.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot cannibalize your input string, i.e. is a read-only, then you can malloc memory for the result in the function, do not forgot to *free* it afterwards:

```
char* subCstring(char * inStr, int start_index, int end_index)
{
    char *out = (char *) malloc(end_index - start_index + 2); // need '2' here to keep '\0'
    strncpy(out, inStr + start_index, end_index-start_index+1);
    return out;
}
```

If the result of your function is consumed before the second call to the function, you can also use static allocation for the results.

```
char* subCstring(char * inStr, int start_index, int end_index)
{
    static char out [256];
    strncpy(out, min(255, inStr + start_index, end_index-start_index+1));
    return out;
}
```

you can also pass allocated memory for the results in arguments.

or you can use 'c++' std::string to do it in a more elegant way.

Comment: Why does it displays garbage values? Any idea to get rid of garbage values after the substring?

Comment: @Dante: What is "garbage" to you?  Please provide a [mcve] showing what you are actually doing.

Comment: Thank you I got solution but I think it's better to use dynamic memory(new) than malloc in c++

Comment: @Dante: in C++, it is best to use `std::string`, let it handle memory for you. It even has a nice `substr()` method.

Comment: are you using 'c' or 'c++'? there is no 'new' in 'c'. in this particular case 'new' and 'malloc' are equivalent, more or less. 'new' calls 'malloc' underneath. In both cases you need to clean afterwards.

Answer (score -1):

```
 char* subCstring(char * inStr, int start_index, int end_index) {
    char * sub = new char[end_index];
    sub[end_index] = '\0';
    strncpy(sub, inStr+start_index, end_index);
    return sub;


}
```

Comment: do provide an explanation as to what this code does and how it would solve the problem.

Comment: This code is not taking `start_index` into account when calculating the new allocation size, and the number of chars to copy. It is assuming `start_index` is always 0, and over-allocates and over-copies when `start_index` is > 0. Also, accessing `sub[end_index]` is always out of bounds, corrupting surrounding memory.

Comment: You need something more like this: `char* subCstring(char * inStr, int start_index, int end_index) { int len = end_index - start_index + 1; char * sub = new char[len+1]; strncpy(sub, inStr+start_index, len); sub[len] = '\0'; return sub; }`